# How can I find maximum width of h4 tag out of all h4 tags in the page if i have given width as fit-content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have 6 `<h4>`-tags in a webpage with `width:fit-content` property.

Now since all these `<h4>`-tags have different content, their width also differs. I want to fix width oh all `<h4>`-tags to one size which equal to maximum width of the content in all these tags.

```css
h4{
margin:2px 0;
padding:0;
background: red;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <h4>Lalilu</h4>
  <h4>Nur der Mann im Mond</h4>
  <h4>schaut mir beim</h4>
  <h4>Editieren zu!</h4>
  <h4>Mist! Jetzt weiß ich nicht</h4>
  <h4>mehr wie das Lied ging...</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: by default `h4` tags are `display:block`. so what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Please visit [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the largest `h4` width with these steps:

1. Collect all the `h4` width values into an array by using [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
2. Get the max value by running `Math.max.apply` on that array ([read more about it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max#Getting_the_maximum_element_of_an_array)).

```js
const allWidth = $('h4').map((index, elm) => elm.clientWidth).get();
const maxWidth = Math.max.apply(null, allWidth);

console.log(maxWidth);
```

```css
h4 {
  background: pink;
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>h4 headline</h4>
<h4>h4 headline h4 headline</h4>
<h4>h4 headline h4 headline h4 headline</h4>
<h4>h4 headline h4 headline h4 headline h4 headline</h4>
```

Comment: @sathish shenoy any thoughts?